# Unit Testing Responsive Javascript, Qunit and matchMedia

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, media-queries, qunit

I am having trouble testing and automating conditional matchMedia statements. I would like to create a unit test that can test many widths (in this case desktop and tablet widths).

I can write a test for each device/media query (e.g. this.setForTablet()) but how do I test the below mini controller?

Is there a practical way to test statements such as the following? Is it a better practice to refactor my code to avoid statements such as the following, if so how?

```
        if ( window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches  ) { // View <= tablet
            this.setForTablet();
        } else { // View > tablet
            this.setForDesktop();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor and return.

Refactor the mini controller to accept different input/widths and return known/expected values for each case. These will be your test assertions.

One should expect matchMedia to works as intended and test only the user/coder's own code.